# Passing touches from UIImageView to superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiresponder

I have four `UIImageViews` placed on a circular `UIView`. Dragging the `UIView` rotates the view. But when I drag the UIImageView, the rotation does not occur. The UIImageView is eating the touches.

I subclassed the UIImageView and tried this:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.superview touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

That doesn't seem to solve the problem. I tried disabling touches on the `UIImageView` - `[imageView setUserInteraction:NO]`. That doesn't solve the problem either. I know there are similar questions been asked. But none seem to solve my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Where you are writing view rotation code.

Comment: @Nagarajan inside the parent UIView

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` on your `UIImageView`s, it should prevent them from consuming the touches.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what you meant by "disabling touches". In case you disable them, is your `touchesMoved:withEvent:` method still called? If yes, then I'd suggest using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to detect the draging.

Comment: Yes. touchesMoved is still called. So I put a pan gesture on the super view? Is there any other way?

Comment: I just tried out the solution with `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO` and for me it works, meaning that only the superview's `touchesMoved:withEvent:` is called (even when I drag on the subview), so something else must be wrong with your setup

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong. Everything seems fine.

Comment: @Anil Maybe you have another subview somewhere there? Did you try to implement `hitTest:withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`? What happens if you put a breakpoint in `hitTest`, does it enter the breakpoint?